# Executing a script inside another script by providing input to other script

Tags: bash, shell

I was just working on 2 scripts `script1.sh` and `script2.sh`

For executing `script2.sh` I need an IP address as input. `./script2.sh 1.1.1.1`.

Now in `script1.sh` I am accepting list of IPs in a text file using a for loop and performing some operations in it.

So in `script1.sh` I wanted to execute `script2.sh` with the current IP and save that result in a particular file.

But when I am trying to execute the script it is giving me an error.

I have tried to execute 2 normal other scripts like:

```
$ cat first.sh
echo "this is script 1"
$ cat second.sh
echo "this is second script"
```

and calling through `sh ./second.sh` inside `first.sh`.

This simple script is working fine for me but the moment I try to pass or give IP address in like `sh ./script2.sh $Ip > test.txt` its not working for me.

I have also tried passing as an argument by sending it in double quotes like `sh ./script2.sh "$Ip" > test.txt` but got errors.

Can anybody help me out in this?

Below is the error:

```
./script2.sh: 92: ./script2.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
./script2.sh: 1: ./script2.sh: cleanup: not found
```

Comment: paste the content of script2.sh

Comment: Format your question as well

Comment: That looks like your script is not a `sh` script but is instead a `bash` script. So stop trying to use `sh` and try using `bash` instead. Either via `bash script2.sh` or by giving `script2.sh` a shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) and executable permissions (`chmod u+x`) and then using `./script2.sh`. Also, as a general rule quoting variable expansions (like you did with `"$Ip"`) is a good idea and you should almost always do that.

Comment: Thanks Etan It did work with bash, Thank you again.